I would like to modify Blender Camera Projection matrix for getting a non unform view scaling for my work
I need to create a small feature where I can scale the camera view non uniformly along horizontal and vertical axis of the camera view. I would prefer to use the region_3d camera view or if that's not possible to be touched then blender's in scene camera (bpy.context.scene.camera) I did a bit of research and found that you can get projeciton matrix as follows,
depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get
projection_matrix = camera.calc_matrix_camera(depsgraph, x=1920, y=1080)

But I did not find a way to set the changed projection matrix back to camera ... there is no api like bpy.context.scene.camera.projection_matrix
Is there any workaround for this ?
Regards,
Atul

How don't existing cameras fit your purpose? "scale the camera view non uniformly along horizontal and vertical axis" - there is pixel aspect ratio and resolution settings for that. What exact functionality are you after?

Yeah the pixel aspect ratio is useful ... but I want to create a 3d view that will render using the camera in scene rather than region_3d camera ...
Example if you set aspect to 2x in horizontal and then check render image option ... the object will look compressed by 0.5x in horizontal direction ...
So, I want that kind of functionality but in a live continuous update mode
